# How can I study the convergence of the improper integral $\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan(x+1)+x}{2^x+3^x}\, \mathrm dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I need to study the convergence of the following improper integral:

$$\int_{2}^{\infty} \dfrac{\arctan(x+1)+x}{2^x+3^x}\, \mathrm dx$$

I did the following:

$$ -\dfrac{\pi}{2} < \arctan(x+1)  < \dfrac{\pi}{2}   \\
\implies -\dfrac{\pi}{2} + x < \arctan(x+1) +x < \dfrac{\pi}{2} +x   \\
\implies   \dfrac{-\dfrac{\pi}{2} + x}{2^x+3^x} <  \dfrac{\arctan(x+1) +x}{2^x+3^x}  < \dfrac{\dfrac{\pi}{2} + x}{2^x+3^x}   \\
$$

I planned to integrate the inequality and then using the comparison criterion to proof its convergence. However, the idea did not work for me.

Comment: $\arctan$ is globally bounded and since $$\int_2^\infty \frac1{2^x+3^x}<\infty,$$ you only need to look at $$\int_2^\infty\frac{x}{2^x+3^x}$$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch you should submit that as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

Just observe that RHS is less than $$\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}+x}{3^x}$$Since $$\int_2^\infty\frac{1}{3^x} \,dx$$clearly converges, it is enough to show that$$\int_2^\infty\frac{x}{3^x} \,dx$$ converges which can be done using limit comparison test (with $g(x)=\frac{1}{e^x}$).

Answer (score 1):

The function $x\mapsto \lvert\arctan(x+1)\rvert$ is globally bounded by $\frac\pi2$ so your integral is bounded in absolute value by $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\frac\pi2+x}{2^x+3^x}\,\mathrm dx<\infty.$$

Note that the last integral is finite because $$\int_0^\infty \frac{P(x)}{b^x}\,\mathrm dx$$ is finite for all polynomials $P$ and numbers $b>1$. This can be proven for example by noting that $$b^x\geq 1+C x^{\mathrm{deg}(P)},$$ where $C=\frac{\ln(b)^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}$ and $\mathrm {deg}(P)$ is the degree of the polynomial $P$.

Answer (score 0):

You have a polynomial function over an exponential one.  This dies fast enough at $\infty$ to integrate there.

Comment: $x$ is not bounded :)